# Пожалуйста помогите разобраться. Не могу получить LastInsertID. Это плагин для osclass. Я начинающий

Tags: php, mysql

Очень прошу, помогите разобраться. Не могу в плагине для osclass, который я пытаюсь сделать получить LastInsertID. Что только не перепробовал. Вот код

```
$conn = DBConnectionClass::newInstance();
$c_db = $conn->getOsclassDb();
$comm = new DBCommandClass($c_db)

define('IMPL_TABLE', DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 't_item');
define('IMPL_TABLEDESK', DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 't_item_description_test');

$valuesitem = array(
              'fk_i_user_id' => $user_id,
              'fk_i_category_id' => $catId,
              'dt_pub_date' => $date_intime,
              'dt_mod_date' => $date_intime,
              'i_price' => $cell5->getValue(),
              'fk_c_currency_code' => 'RUB',
              's_contact_name' => $prepare['s_contact_name'],
              's_contact_email' => $prepare['s_contact_email'],
              's_ip' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
              'b_premium' => '0',
              'b_enabled' => '1',
              'b_active' => '1',
              'b_spam' => '0',
              's_secret' => $secret,
              'b_show_email' => '0',
            );
              $comm->insert(IMPL_TABLE, $valuesitem);

//$lid = Здесь и должен быть LastInsertID.

$valuesitemdesk = array(
              'fk_i_item_id' => $lid,
              'fk_c_locale_code' => 'ru_RU',
              's_title' => $cell1->getValue(),
              's_description' => $cell2->getValue(),
            );

$comm->insert(IMPL_TABLEDESK, $valuesitemdesk);

exit;
```

Comment: `$id = $comm->insertedId()`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как-же всё просто. Искренне благодарен.